# How to Clone Repository from Perforce to Git?

Tags: windows, git, gitlab, perforce, git-clone

I'm trying to import repository from Perforce to Git. I Installed Git Bash for windows and executed the following commands.

```
p4 login

export P4PORT="tcp:Servername:1111"

p4 set P4USER="user1"


git config --global alias.p4 ! "python 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4'"'

p4 clone //Projects/Test1@all
```

But I am getting the error : Nothing to do - existing dvcs tree at .p4root

Comment: `p4 clone` is going to clone a new local Perforce instance.  I think you want to be using some `git-p4` command?

Comment: I tried the link: http://ericlathrop.com/2012/12/how-to-set-up-git-p4-in-windows/, but its giving an error command not found

Comment: Usually if you get a "command not found" error it means you forgot to install something, but not knowing which command produced that error I can't guess what the something might have been.  Good luck!  :)

Comment: After correcting the path etc, now the git p4 import command giving the error " "failure accessing depot: could not connect"

Comment: @SamStafford, I installed Python 2.7.3 and its working now. Previously I used Python 3.7